# How to build streamsets datacollector edge without error?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, streamsets

When tried to build datacollector edge, I get the below error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'datacollector-edge'. 
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'. 
> Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.github.blindpirate:gogradle:0.11.4. Required by: project : 
> com.github.blindpirate.gogradle:com.github.blindpirate.gogradle.gradle.plugin:0.11.4 
> Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.github.blindpirate:gogradle:0.11.4. 
> Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/github/blindpirate/gogradle/0.11.4/gogradle-0.11.4.pom'. 
> Could not GET 'https://plugins-artifacts.gradle.org/gradle.plugin.com.github.blindpirate/gogradle/0.11.4/b160735df9ebb516b2b73294dacef27ea3db5d42de86474a0a46a553b447bd03/gogradle-0.11.4.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden 
> Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.gitversion:gradle-git-version:0.12.0-rc2. Required by: project : 
> com.palantir.git-version:com.palantir.git-version.gradle.plugin:0.12.0-rc2 
> Could not resolve gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.gitversion:gradle-git-version:0.12.0-rc2. 
> Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/palantir/gradle/gitversion/gradle-git-version/0.12.0-rc2/gradle-git-version-0.12.0-rc2.pom'. 
> Could not GET 'https://plugins-artifacts.gradle.org/gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.gitversion/gradle-git-version/0.12.0-rc2/a26da57e1d890aaaa6ec3e0e6f3d6e9dbbc12d92a2099857b73de15c3fc0aeb6/gradle-git-version-0.12.0-rc2.pom'. 

Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Comment: The files download fine for me. Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Yes. I have already set it in the gradle.properties

Comment: And does your proxy require user credentials to access? Or could it be that the proxy denies that domain?